# Merging MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, linux

I have two SQL files. Both having same database name and same table structure but different data. How can I merge these two SQL files into one database?

Comment: It depends on whether the two sql files has conflict keys. But even if they conflict, you can choose to ignore conflicts and continue importing.

Comment: please provide at least some basic information.

Comment: Looks like user is talking about merging two dumps from databases with equivalent schemas into a new combined database. Fixing grammar and changing language to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is different, including keys,

- restore your first sql
- rename the database, eg db2
- restore second sql
- Copy data over using 'INSERT INTO db1.mytable SELECT * FROM db2.mytable '

If your data set clashes, your either going to have to do some manual data manipulation, or use a data merge [tool](http://www.altova.com/databasespy/database-compare-tool.html).